# Multiple SQL statements in PHP

Tags: php, sql

Just asking is it possible in php to perform sql statment's in 1 function.

What my sql really does is fetch data from three tables in my database.
I am currently unsure of what method to use. Inner join would pop into it but i forgot what the proper syntax. so i was thinking about this.

```
$qry_display = "SELECT student_id,
section_id,level,photo,address,father_occupation,father_phone,father_company,mother_occupation,
mother_phone,mother_company 
from tbl_er 
where student_id='$id' AND level="3rd Year"";
```

The above statement would retrieve the information from tbl_er these would be the students history.

```
$qry_display = "SELECT fname,
sex,
lname,
mname,
birth_date,
birth_place,
address,
father,
father_degree,
mother,
mother_degree,
from tbl_enroll where student_id='$id'";
```

The above statement would retrieve part of the information from tbl_enroll these would be the students core unchangeable data. Also the first statement has "section_id" to be retrieved. so my idea is to retrieve that value so it would be used for the last sql which is.

```
$qry_display = "SELECT section_name,adviser_id,schoolyr 
from tbl_section 
where student_id='$id' AND section_id='$sid'";
```

and my idea to on how to get the section_id is before the last statement i would put.

```
    $sid= section_id  (I am unsure if this will work.)
```

Also will this statement trigger all three statements in one function?

```
        $sql_display = mysql_query($qry_display) or die (mysql_error());
```

Thank you, Appreciate any feedback.

Comment: You might be interested in [mysqli::multi_query](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php).

Comment: @ACJ I am not able to view it.

Comment: You are not able to view the PHP Manual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot wrong with this, and you probably will not get what you are looking for even if you work out the bugs, so lets start with writing this as 1 coherent query with left joins (good call btw).

```
$qry_display = "SELECT
            a.student_id, a.section_id, a.level, a.photo, a.address, a.father_occupation, a.father_phone, a.father_company, a.mother_occupation, a.mother_phone, a.mother_company,
            b.fname, b.sex, b.lname, b.mname, b.birth_date, b.birth_place, b.address, b.father, b.father_degree, b.mother, b.mother_degree,
            c.section_name, c.adviser_id, c.schoolyr
            FROM tbl_er AS a
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_enroll AS b ON a.student_id = b.student_id
            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_section AS c ON a.section_id = c.section_id
            WHERE a.student_id=".$id." AND a.level='3rd Year'";
```

The last join doesn't care about the student_id because the section / advisor relationship does not depend on a student.

Comment: Knew i was smelling inner join. Thanks I will go digging into this right away.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to recall that the `MySQL` family of functions doesn't handle multiple statements in a single `mysql_query` operation. It'll perform the first statement and then silently discard the following ones, even if you wrap them in a transaction.

That said, the MySQL family is deprecated - [you should be using MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli_query) for new projects in 2012. ;)

Comment: Expecting your answer. But thank you. Unable to use MySQLi and learn it right now cause i have to finish this within a week. So might be looking into UNION or INNERJOIN.

Comment: Why are you unable to use MySQLi? If you absolutely cannot, your only option is to perform the database operations successively.

Comment: Just heard of it right now and i may not be able to learn it in time because i have Reports function in my system to finish.

Comment: MySQLi isn't what I'd call difficult, but depending on how big your system is you might be right that replacing everything is a bad idea. You could likely get away for using MySQLi for this part and then phasing the old MySQL functions out gradually from the rest of the application.